# How Can I Get a Stable Triangle Wave With Adjustable Frequency

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, low-pass, diy, function-generator

I am trying to make a wave generator. It will have switch modes for frequency between 1.6kHz to 1.6Hz with x10 increments. Everything is set except the triangle wave. I use a wien birdge oscillator to create a clean sine wave, then integrate it to get a square and filter it to get a triangle wave.

[image: circuit]

**when switch is at position one, oscillator (using 1nF capacitors) is generating a sine wave with frequency of 1.6KHz, everything works perfect except that little plateau on the triangle wave**

[image: 1.6KHz]

**When I switch to second position (which switches oscillator to 10nF capacitors) I get a trimmed triangle wave**

[image: trimmed triangle wave]

**I obtain the triangle wave by filtering the square wave with a low pass filter than amplifying it with an opAmp.**

[image: triangle wave part]

Amplified sine wave passes through the R13 then gets integrated.
Integrated sine wave(square wave) passes through R14, gets filtered and becomes a triangle wave. Then gets amplified. I tried using another integrator circuit to obtain the triangle wave but it doesnt work. I believe I need some kind of auto gain, so the gain of opAmp will adjust itself after I change frequency in a way that it will not create a huge triangle wave which gets trimmed. I thought using back to back diodes like in the oscillator but couldnt make it work. I thought about removing last amplifier but then the output becomes very low.

Comment: *How Can I Get a Stable...* How stable? This is an analog oscillator, it drifts over temperature, supply and lots of other parameters. Despite that, there are plenty of "good" analog waveform generators that can are "stable enough" depending on what is needed. You could search for service manuals with schematics of such "old style" analog waveform generators to learn how it is done.

Comment: Do note that, to reach the **next level** of stability, you need to go **digital**. Have a look at a DDS chip like the AD9833, you can buy a module with such an AD9833 which can be programmed using an Arduino. Almost all modern waveform generators use the same principle (a DDS) that this IC uses. I admit that that is **much less educational** than building an analog waveform generator. It all depends on what your goal is with this project.

Comment: Can I just ask why you're building this? Do you need a pointy waveform for some other project, or is it simply for the fun of learning how to make this one?

Comment: @PaulUszak ı wanted to make an antenna to play electromagnetic waves but I realized I need an AC source for it to work. I wanted to make it on my own, I learnt about oscillators, one thing led to another and for both educational reasons and that I realized Im gonna need a function generator eventually, I decided to build one.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Well stable might be the wrong word. I just want to get rid of the plateau and make sure that the triangle doesnt get distorted when I switch frequencies like in the last plot.

Comment: Cool. It's just that I ask this as I believe that it's better to only build what you can't buy.  If you want to learn, then great. But my brother has one of [these](https://www.amazon.co.uk/KKmoon-1HZ-500KHZ-Functional-Generator-Triangle/dp/B0748H1ZPM) and it's surprisingly good (ATMega chip + resistance ladder).

Comment: @PaulUszak this is digital rigth?

Comment: Yeh. Crystal controlled. It's the simplest way to get the range of forms and frequencies. I like it for £30. I don't sell them :-)

Comment: Any suggestions?